# Casting from object to T without casting operator (T)instance

Tags: c#, reflection

I have two generic classes: A and B:

```
    // There we must know what T type parameter represents.
    public class A<TItem>
    {
        public void Method(IEnumerable<TItem> sequence)
        {
        }
    }

    // TObject can be everyone type. It is not constrained.
    public class B<TObject>
    {
        public void Method(TObject obj)
        {
            // Assume that we ensured that obj is IEnumerable<>.
        }
    }
```

Suppose that I [constructed instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/how-to-examine-and-instantiate-generic-types-with-reflection#constructing-an-instance-of-a-generic-type) of generic type `A<IEnumerable<T>>`. But the variable type of it is `object`. Is there some decision to cast `object` to `A<IEnumerable<T>>`?

Comment: Start reading [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/how-to-examine-and-instantiate-generic-types-with-reflection) and update your question.

Comment: I bumped on this problem while writing my library for controlling output. https://yadi.sk/d/q-6Wq2SWjjhsZA Problem in FormatProvider. And what would you advise me about generics? My goal is to allow user write FormatProvider<T>.Default such IEqualityComparer<T>.Default.

Comment: Question still unclear

Comment: I don't think your edit made things any more clear... Post now shows couple unrelated classes and asks how to do cast from some third type without cast... Additionally your comment  "My goal is to allow user write FormatProvider<T>.Default " does not look related to the question (at least I can't see any connection).

Comment: You're posting a few classes - `A` and `B`, and then asking about `Example`, which isn't shown. It's confusing because we read the first sentence and the code sample, and our minds naturally expect the question to be about those, not about something entirely different.

Answer (score 0):

You're question is a bit hard to understand, so clarification might provide better answers.
You can create an instance of `A` by simply calling:

```
var myA = new A<string>();
```

The `Method` method on that class would than on a signature like this:

```
public void Method(IEnumerable<string> sequence)
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this what you were planning.

```
public class A<TItem>
    {
        public void Method(IEnumerable<TItem> sequence)
        {
        }
    }

    // TObject can be everyone type. It is not contrained.
    public class B<TObject>
    {
        public void Method(TObject obj)
        {
            // Assume that we ensured that obj is IEnumerable<>, but how to create instance of A?
            // May be there is another way to solve this problem...


            A<dynamic> f = new A<dynamic>();

            IEnumerable<string> list = new List<string>();

            f.Method(list);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. But I try avoid `dynamic` due to it's possibility to kill the performance. But it's - a possible decision. =)

Comment: @MrFresnel - Don't worry about killing performance until you have a performance problem. Don't prematurely optimize.